# Vim : sorting Todo list

Tags: sorting, vim

Let us suppose I have a todolist, each line including the same structure of items :

`Do something, @priority (e.g. : @1, @2, etc…), §project (e.g. : §vacation, §family, etc…),  &category (e.g.: &call, &do, etc…)`

Each of these 4 items has a variable length, of course.

I know how to sort on the "Do something" part. But how can I sort such a list by @priority ? or by §project ? or by &category ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should check out [todo.sh](http://todotxt.com/), this is the [github repository](https://github.com/ginatrapani/todo.txt-cli/).  They have already solved many of these kind of problems with a text todo file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should read `:help sort`, the third example for the `/pattern/` argument seems to apply very well to your problem.

Quick and dirty sorting by priority:

```
:%sort /.\{-}\ze@/
```

Quick and dirty sorting by project:

```
:%sort /.\{-}\ze§/
```

Quick and dirty sorting by category:

```
:%sort /.\{-}\ze&/
```

*EDIT*

The commands above were adhoc modifications of the examples found in the docs. ib is right that they might be too verbose. As per his comment, the commands below are a lot shorter:

```
:sort /@/
:sort /§/
:sort /&/
```

*END EDIT*

Comment: Quick and dirty ? It works beautifully ! Thanks. I now have a simple VimDo list...

Comment: Quick and dirty because it won't work if you use @, § or & outside of their standard use: `Twit @romainl about new project @1 §new&coolproject &category`.

Comment: Yes, of course. Nevertheless efficient for a Q&D todolist ("Perfect" is sometimes contrary to "well enough"). Thanks again.

Comment: @ThG:  If I am not mistaken, these commands contain a lot of redundant characters.  The `:sort/@/`, `:sort/§/`, `:sort/&/` commands do the same as the ones above.

Comment: Yes, that's another reason why they are "dirty". Thanks ib.

Comment: @romainl:  It is a matter of taste, but I would like to note that the leading percent sign is indeed redundant: If the range for the `:sort` command is omitted, it processes the whole buffer anyway (see `:h :sort`).